VSCODE Jupyter feature where, on "run all" or "run cells above", cells with errors are pointed so we can jump to them easily?
Say my layout is
- Cell 1
-- Cell 1.1
-- Cell 1.2
--- Cell 1.2.1
--- ....
----- ....
....
....
- Cell n

If I am working cell n and run all cells above it or run all cells from top and get an error somewhere I don't seem to find an easy way to jump to the exact erroneous cell at once.
Currently, on a fold-all mode, I have to unfold every cell from 1 .. n-1 and their successors to be able to find where the red highlight is.
The best I get so far is in the erroneous cell number in the output window.
Ideally, a link or some sort on pointer on the notebook itself (not the output window) would be great.
Even a hierarchical section highlight would work.
Or even better, a red highlight on the left or right bars which when clicked takes us to the troubled cell.
Do any of these exist? and if so, where can I find them?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
